# Como recibir un Array Post sin nombre en PHP

Tags: php, java, volley

Estoy haciendo un proyecto JAVA en el que envió un JSONARRAY al servidor usando la biblioteca Volley. Este array no tiene un nombre especificado,

¿Alguien sabe como capturar en PHP este array POST que no tiene un nombre?

Este el Request que hago al servidor, donde "array" es el JsonArray multidimensional.

```
JsonArrayRequest request_json = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_CARRO, array,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
```

Como ve, se envía directamente el JsonArray como argumento y ,por ende, desconozco como capturarlo en el PHP.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir un [mre]. Que tú sepas lo que estás haciendo no significa que otros vayan a saberlo, y SO no está para ayudarte solo a ti, está para ayudar a *TODOS*. Si no indicas lo que estás haciendo y lo ejemplificas es posible que otra persona con exactamente la misma duda no entienda tu pregunta y no sepa que la solución de abajo es útil para él también. Aquí no trabajamos para ti, trabajamos para ayudar a todos, así que por favor usa el botón [edit] y haz que tu pregunta sea útil no solo para ti.

Comment: Lo que mandes al servidor debe leerse según la estructura que tenga el contenido enviado. Si es una cadena se leería como tal, si es un array entonces tendrías que iterar sobre él para obtener sus elementos. Si en ese array hay objetos JSON entonces debes convertirlo a objetos y leer cada elemento por sus nombres de propiedad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces la peticion DEBES realizar una asociacion de llaves y valores del tipo:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    Map<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put("nombre", nombre);
    params.put("apellido", apellido);

    return params;
}
```

Si es así, ese `"nombre"` y `"apellido"` son las llaves que usaras en PHP para obtener los datos:

```
<?php
  $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
  $apellido = $POST["apellido"]
```

Te dejo [esta guía](https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/php/enviar-solicitud-de-publicacion-con-volley-y-recibir-en-php/1049604623/) para que aclares las dudas que puedas tener :)

EDICION

De acuerdo al comentario, puedes tener los datos usando algo similar a esto:

```
$datos = json_decode($_POST["datos"]);
foreach( $datos as $key => $dato) {
    echo $dato->id;
    echo $dato->typeName;
}
```

La función `json_decode` convierte un json en un objeto de PHP en el cual puedes hacer un foreach para tener los datos de cada objeto que envias.

[Documentacion de PHP - foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Sucede que el array que estoy recibiendo es multidimensional, es decir, una array con arrays dentro, ¿Que hago en este caso? Ejemplo: [{"id":1,"typeName":"La Americana"},{"id":1,"typeName":"La Americana"},{"id":1,"typeName":"La Americana"}]

Comment: En ese caso puedes usar algo parecido a: `$datos = json_decode($_POST["datos"]);
foreach( $datos as $key => $dato) {
    echo $dato->id;
    echo $dato->typeName;
}` mejor lo pongo en la respuesta para mejor visual

Comment: Hola SMN947, gracias a ti entendí como funciona el json_decode y pude lograr enviar el array con getParams.